# MySQL .NET Connector issue with stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql, mysql

I have a VB.NET application that has been accessing MySQL stored procedures using .NET Connector 5.0.7.  We recently upgraded to .NET Connector 5.2.6 and I now receive the following error:

"Procedure or function 'proc_scheduleProcess' cannot be found in database 'ProjectMgr'."

The following code has been running without issue until the upgrade, and I've verified that the connection string is pointing to the correct database:

```
Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

conn.ConnectionString =
    ConnectionStrings.Item("MYSQL_DIRECT").ConnectionString.ToString()

conn.Open()

Dim cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.CommandText = "proc_scheduleProcess"

cmd.Connection = conn

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?  Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two things to debug your problem:

- Use the MySqlAdmin to check the log and see exactly how the connector is making the call to the DB (you'll need to have your query logs enabled)
- Download the source code for the connector and add it to your project to debug the actual code that is configuring the call

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced when using the data source configuration wizard in VS2008 that it will often execute MySQL stored procedures that I am trying to add to the dataset designer. Its a bit disconcerting to see rows appear out of nowhere. I can't see how this should be intended behaviour. I get the same error as you when my stored proc has parameters. After that error, server explorer will no longer expand db details. Would be great to hear more feedback on this issue from people trying to get MySQL stored procs to work with .NET